# Get All in Realm returns deleted Items

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I implementing a recycler view that gets its data set from a realm database using rx-java. When i delete items from the data set then call get all items, i receive the remaining items plus the items i just deleted but invalidated.

```
Observable.defer(list -> {
        boolean isDeleted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            isDeleted = isDeleted && evictById(list.get(i));
        return Observable.just(isDeleted);
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber{
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) { }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean success) {
            if (success) 
                getUserList();
        }
    });

boolean evictById(final int itemId){
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmModel toDelete = mRealm.where(UserRealmModel.class).equalTo("userId", itemId).findFirst();
    if (toDelete != null) {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        RealmObject.deleteFromRealm(toDelete);
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        return !RealmObject.isValid(toDelete);
    } else return false;
}

public void getUserList(){
   Observable.from(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(UserRealmModel.class).findAll())
             .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<UserRealmModel>> {
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted() {
                      hideViewLoading();
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                  @Override
                  public void onNext(List<UserViewModel> users) {
                      showUsersCollectionInView(users);
                  });
}
```

For example the data set has 10 items, i delete 3 of them. In the getUserList response i receive a list of 10 items with 7 valid items and 3  invalid.
Also i made sure, using a realm browser, that the items deleted!
Can someone please explain why is this happening ?

Comment: this definitely sounds like a side-effect of the 0.89.0 breaking change in order to support iterators.

Comment: Maybe, I am using 0.90.0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are indirectly deleting items that are part of query result, and it is correct that is part of the breaking changes of 0.89. Instead you should remove them directly from your query result.

```
public boolean evictById(UserRealmModel obj) {
  obj.deleteFromRealm()
  return true;
}

// should be

public boolean evictById(RealmResults list, int index) {
  list.deleteFromRealm(index);
  return true;
}
```

You didn't provide the implementation of `evictById` so I'm guessing your method does more as well, but hopefully you get the idea.

Also any query run *after* you deleted some objects should never contain deleted objects.

Comment: Although i think you solution would work, but the thing is that i am using clean architecture and i do some mapping to the results before receiving them on the presentation layer. So i dont have access to the RealmResults list.
Also i added my implementation of evictById()

Comment: Your `evictById` is not a presentation layer method. It belongs in the data layer where it could have access to the list.